# JQuery easing not working on google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

When using the JQuery [easing plugin](https://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/), it seems to not work on google chrome or Microsoft edge,  while it works perfectly on safari. It is supposed to scroll down on page load with a really nice easing effect but just does normal smooth scrolling.

Here is the only part of my javascript file where I used the ease:

```
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#destination").offset().top
  }, 3000, "easeInOutQuint");
```

Why is this happening? Any solution?

Comment: is it only `easeInOutQuint` ? what about `easeOutCubic`? does that also "not work"?

Comment: @JaromandaX I experimented with all the eases but they don't seem to work.